# How do I check if I can use the allowed_block_types filter?

Tags: filters, block-editor

For a WordPress theme I deregister a few blocks for Gutenberg (in fact, I only register the ones I need).

For this, I use a filter:

```
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types', 'amb_allowed_block_types' );
```

This filter hooks into a function like this:

```
function amb_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks ) {

    return [
        'core/paragraph',
        'core/image',
        'core/heading',
        'core/gallery',
...
```

This works nice. But I don't want to use this filter if it is being used on a WP theme that doesn't have Gutenberg enabled. How can I make sure that this filter is only being used on Gutenberg sites?

Many thanks!

Comment: That filter won't do anything if they don't have the Block Editor enabled, so you shouldn't need to do anything additional.

Comment: Hi @WebElaine thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the current theme supports Gutenberg blocks inside your function

```php
function amb_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks ) {
    if(! current_theme_supports('wp-block-styles') ){
        return $allowed_blocks;
    }
    return [
        'core/paragraph',
        'core/image',
        'core/heading',
        'core/gallery',
...
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thank you for your help! I tried the code, but unfortunately it doesn't work. All blocks still show up, instead of the selected blocks..

Comment: in this docs https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/themes/theme-support/#default-block-styles , the themes that supports Gutenberg may use this `add_theme_support( 'wp-block-styles' );` based on that we check if the theme supports `'wp-block-styles'`, may be the theme ignore it and use another indicator